# How to generate plists from rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plist

I'm rather new at ruby (on rails) and I can't figure this one out;
What is the best way to serialize objects to plist in rails?
I'm using the plist library from rubyforge.
And I have nested_attributes:

```
class Deck  
deck has_many :cards  
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards  

class Card  
belongs_to :deck
```

I've tried in the deck controller to do this:

```
format.plist { render :plist => @deck.to_plist }
```

But I don't get the cards...
Similar in xml, I can do this:

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @deck.to_xml(:include => :cards) }
```

And get the desired output.
Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registred the mime type in your environment.rb ?

```
Mime::Type.register "text/plist", :plist
```

this could help http://blog.willj.net/2010/01/25/generating-a-plist-file-in-rails/

bye

Comment: Used a builder, like in the link you provided... Thank you!