# Missing Template Error When Calling Render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

#### The error

```
 ForumsController create should work for plist
 Failure/Error: post :create, :name => "My New Shiny Forum", :format => 'plist'
 Missing template forums/create with {:formats=>[:plist], :handlers=>[:builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :erb, :rjs], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/maletor/Sites/3md/app/views", ..."
 # ./app/controllers/forums_controller.rb:64:in `create'
 # ./app/controllers/forums_controller.rb:61:in `create'
 # ./app/controllers/forums_controller.rb:52:in `create'
 # ./spec/controllers/forums_controller_spec.rb:222
```

#### ./spec/controllers/forums_controller_spec.rb:222

```
post :create, :name => "My New Shiny Forum", :format => 'plist'
```

#### ./app/controllers/forums_controller.rb#create

```
def create
  Forum.transaction do 
    if Forum.find_by_name(params[:name])
      head :conflict
      return
    end
    group = Group.create!(:name => params[:name])
    forum = Forum.create!(:name => params[:name])

    respond_to do |format|
      Rails.logger.debug "FORUM: #{forum.inspect}"
      format.json { render :json => forum, :status => 201 }
      format.plist { render :plist => forum, :status => 201 }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733810/how-to-generate-plists-from-rails-models

Comment: have you configured appropriate mime type ?

Comment: Yes. `Mime::Type.register "application/x-plist", :plist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not cover any code in controller into transaction, it uses on Model layer by conventions. You can create the group on a callback after_create in Forum model

Comment: This is true, but unrelated to the issue.

Comment: **return** inside the transaction can get to the unexpected behavior. Try this out

Comment: btw, do you have any views with the **create** in name? json/html, some

Comment: any views care about the **return** case?

Comment: There is not even a folder `app/views/controllers`

This happened when upgrading from Rails 2 to 3.

Removing return statement did nothing to change the failure.

Comment: **respond_to  format...** is looking for corresponding to action name template. You nees to have this one, else put the filename to render or redirect to a page if necessary

Comment: @mikhailov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1646/discussion-between-maletor-and-mikhailov)